# How to replace an element of a list?

Tags: list

Is there a way to replace an item in a list?

```el
(replace-element-in-list (elem-src elem-dst ls &optional times comparison-fn)) 
 ;; ...
 )
```

Example use:
`(replace-element-in-list 1 100 '(3 2 1)) => '(3 2 100)`

Comment: See "*How to replace nth element of a list ...*":  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440069/emacs-how-to-replace-nth-element-of-a-list-with-a-let-bound-variable

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non destructive version.

```lisp
(defun replace-element-in-list (elem-src elem-dst ls &optional times comparison-fn)
  (setq times (or times (length ls)))
  (mapcar
   (lambda (item)
     (cond
      ((and (> times 0)
            (funcall (or comparison-fn #'eq) item elem-src))
       (cl-decf times)
       elem-dst)
      (t
       item)))
   ls))

(replace-element-in-list 2 "2" '(1 2 3 2 4))
;; => (1 "2" 3 "2" 4)

(replace-element-in-list 2 "2" '(1 2 3 2 4) 1)
;; => (1 "2" 3 2 4)

(replace-element-in-list "2" 2 '("1" "2" "3" "2" "4") nil #'string=)
;; => ("1" 2 "3" 2 "4")
```

Comment: `(length ls)` seems unnecessary, could use `most-positive-fixnum` instead, or allow it to be `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

```el
(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-substitute 100 1 '(3 2 1))
```

gives `(3 2 100)`.

```el
(cl-substitute 100 1 '(3 2 1 2 1 2 1) :count 2)
```

gives  `(3 2 100 2 100 2 1)`.

```el
(cl-substitute 100 "one" '("three" "two" "one") :test #'string-equal)
```

gives `("three" "two" 100)`.

Furthermore, there are the keyword arguments `:start`, `:end`, and `:from-end`. See [the doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Sequence-Functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't specify what "replacement" means. Does it mean create and return a new list that is like the original one except for the indicated parts? Or does it mean replace in place, that is, modify the original list?

Here is an example that modifies the original list, i.e., a "destructive" operation.

```lisp
(defun replace-element-in-list (old new xs)
  (let ((tail  (member old xs)))
    (while tail
      (setcar tail new)
      (setq tail  (member old tail))))
  xs)

(replace-element-in-list 1 100 (list 3 1 2 1)) ; => (3 100 2 100)
```

If you want an optional `comparison-function` parameter, then use `(funcall comparison-function ...)` instead of `(member...)`, and default it to `member`.

If you want an optional `times` parameter then initialize a local counter to `0` and compare it to `times` in the `while` test etc.

```lisp
(defun replace-element-in-list (old new xs &optional times compare-fn)
  (let ((count  0)
        tail)
    (setq compare-fn  (or compare-fn  #'member)
          tail        (funcall compare-fn old xs))
    (while (and tail  (or (not times)
                          (<= (setq count  (1+ count)) times)))
      (setcar tail new)
      (setq tail  (funcall compare-fn old tail))))
  xs)

(replace-element-in-list 1 100 (list 3 1 2 1 5 1 1 6))
; => (3 100 2 100 5 100 100 6)

(replace-element-in-list 1 100 (list 3 1 2 1 5 1 1 6) 3)
; => (3 100 2 100 5 100 1 6)

(setq x  (list 1))

(replace-element-in-list x 100 (list 3 '(1) 2 x 5 (copy-sequence x) x 6) nil #'memq)
; => (3 (1) 2 100 5 (1) 100 6)

(replace-element-in-list x 100 (list 3 '(1) 2 x 5 (copy-sequence x) x 6) 1 #'memq)
; => (3 (1) 2 100 5 (1) (1) 6)
```